# Sort an array alphabetically in Ruby but with capitalised words at the end

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort a string alphabetically in Ruby. The problem is, it puts the capitalized words at the beginning of the string, but I want them at the end.

My original string is: `["Apple", "banana", "Zebra", "orange"]`

What I want: `["banana", "orange", "Apple", "Zebra"]`

Comment: The example output has different strings than the input. Just for completeness, could you show how you are currently sorting, and what the output is for the example. That is relatively trivial, but it should help when discussing an answer if we use same var names etc

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What exactly is unclear about this question? She wants the array sorted as specified and can neither use `.sort` (sorts alphabetically instead of sorting by case, then alphabetically) nor `.sort.reverse`

Comment: @awendt: It is clear but "I want" questions without code will attract downvotes regardless. It seems fairly trivial to fix that

Comment: @NeilSlater It's an "I'm trying to" question. Please don't forget we're all here to learn, and judging from the reputation, it's her first question.

Comment: One point worth clarifying: Is "AArdvark" before or after "Zebra" in the desired sort?

Comment: "I'm trying to" is not a question. It is just a statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We need to see what you've tried. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Sorry it's my first question on Stack Overflow...I will take your comments onboard next time I post, thanks for replying!

Comment: @KateBeavis don't forget to mark the accepted answer

Comment: @NeilSlater, aardvark is *way* before zebra.  Early relatives of the aardvark appeared in Africa around the end of the Paleocene (66 to 56 million years ago), whereas zebras evolved from Old World horses within the last 4 million years.

Answer (score 13):

Swap the case for sorting:

```
["Apple", "banana", "Zebra", "orange"].sort_by(&:swapcase)
#=> ["banana", "orange", "Apple", "Zebra"]
```

Comment: Plus 10 for cleverness.

Comment: Probably not a concern, but `["iPhone", "item"].sort_by(&:swapcase) #=> ["item", "iPhone"]`, `["IRB", "It"].sort_by(&:swapcase) #=> ["It", "IRB"]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland not sure if this is actually wrong …

Comment: See third paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabetical_order). Whether the ordering is correct or not is really beside the point. I just wanted to flag it.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to sort the string but move capitalized words to the end of the sorting algorithm.

This works if only the first character is capitalized:

```
p ["banana", "Banana","orange", "Apple", ].sort_by{|x| [x[0].upcase==x[0] ? 1:0,x] }   #=> ["banana", "orange", "Apple", "Banana"]
p ["banana", "Banana","orange", "Apple", ].sort                                        #=> ["Apple", "Banana", "banana", "orange"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Apparently according to Cary Swoveland, this will be faster than using sort_by, and I'm inclined to believe him because `sort` is already so well optimized.

```
def new_sort(array)
  cap, non = array.partition {|el|el[0] == el[0].upcase}
  non.sort + cap.sort
end

puts new_sort ["Apple", "banana", "Zebra", "orange"]
# banna
# orange
# Apple
# Zebra

puts new_sort ["THREE", "two", "one",]
# one
# two
# THREE
```

Comment: My money is on this being fastest among the solutions offered. It allows the use of `sort`, which is substantially faster than `sort_by`, and partitioning, then sorting arrays of size `m` and `n` should be faster than sorting one `m+n` array.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way:

```
arr = %w{ Apple banana Zebra Camel iPhone waffles Pancakes }
  # => ["Apple", "banana", "Zebra", "Camel", "iPhone", "waffles", "Pancakes"] 

arr.sort.rotate(arr.count { |s| s[/^[A-Z]/] }) 
  # => ["banana", "iPhone", "waffles", "Apple", "Camel", "Pancakes", "Zebra"]
```

We have:

```
a = arr.sort
  # => ["Apple", "Camel", "Pancakes", "Zebra", "banana", "iPhone", "waffles"]

nbr_capitalized_words = arr.count { |s| s[/^[A-Z]/] }
  #=> 4

a.rotate(nbr_capitalized_words)
  #=> ["banana", "iPhone", "waffles", "Apple", "Camel", "Pancakes", "Zebra"]
```