# Ruby custom string sort

Tags: ruby, string, sorting

Input string:

```
1654AaBcDddeeFF
```

Output string:

```
1456acddeeABDFF
```

Code I tried:

```
test_array = []
'1654AaBcDddeeFF'.each_byte do |char|
  test_array << char
end

test_array.sort.pack('C*')
# => 1456ABDFFacddee
```

But I would like to see the upper case characters at last.

Comment: So you have to try to make your program not case sensitive.

Comment: You can overload <=> and write some custom sorting.

Comment: @ChaseGilliam not to be a nazi but "overloading" is not a ruby convention or even possible. Jörg W Mittag Wrote an [excellent post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9380268/1978251) explaining this concept. Also [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) will allow you to specify any custom sorting you want

Comment: @engineersmnky ok, you are correct. You can however def <=> ... end and yeah, Array#sort is a better approach.

Comment: Reminds me of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28413845/477037

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since @hirolau's already taken `swapcase`, I offered an alternative (even though I prefer his answer). Alas, @Stefan identified a flaw, but suggested a nice fix:

```
str = '1654AaBcDddeeFF'

order_array = [*'0'..'9',*'a'..'z',*'A'..'Z']
str.each_char.sort_by { |c| order_array.index(c) }.join
  #=> "1456acdeABDF"
```

(I am a mere scribe.)

One advantage of this approach is that you could use it for other orderings. For example, if:

```
str = '16?54!AaBcDdde,eFF'
```

and you also wanted to group the characters `'!?,' at the beginning, in that order, you could write:

```
order_array = [*'!?,'.chars,*'0'..'9',*'a'..'z',*'A'..'Z']
str.each_char.sort_by { |c| order_array.index(c) }.join
  #=> "!?,1456acdeABDF"
```

We can make this a bit more efficient by converting `order_array` to a hash. For the last example:

```
order_hash = Hash[order_array.each_with_index.to_a]
```

then:

```
str.each_char.sort_by { |c| order_hash[c] }.join
  # => "!?,1456acddeeABDFF"
```

Comment: Note that this removes duplicate characters.

Comment: You could use an `order` array and `sort_by { |c| order.index(c) }`

Comment: Looks nice. But is actual sorting happening here ? Like say are they sorted based on ASCII values when it comes to special characters ? To me it looks like mere grouping when it comes to symbols but am not sure, please enlighten me

Comment: @Appunu, you'd have to include the special characters in order_array. For example, if `str = 'βΔ3Rαe'` and we want to modify my example to put the Greek letters at the end (lower then upper case), we would need `order_array = [*'0'..'9',*'a'..'z',*'A'..'Z',*'α'..'ω',*'Α'..'Ω']`, `str.each_char.sort_by { |c| order_array.index(c) }.join #=> "3eRαβΔ"`. Note also `str.each_char.map(&:swapcase).join #=> "βΔ3rαE"`.

Comment: Eventhough I accepted the previous answer. This solution provided by @CarySwoveland is the optimal one under various situations where we need to involve special characters and symbols.

Answer (score 13):

What about this?

```
p '1654AaBcDddeeFF'.each_char.sort_by(&:swapcase).join #=> "1456acddeeABDFF"
```

Edit: As @Cary Swoveland pointed out `.chars` is just a shortcut for `.each_char.to_a` and since we do not need to `to_a` here `.each_char` is a better method to use

Comment: Thats a very sneaky answer. Loved the approach though. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice one. Maybe `each_char` rather than `chars` to avoid the creation of a temporary array.

Comment: Had to think about this one for a while. Very clever.