# Ruby: how to sort array of string parsing the content

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, parsing, sorting

Here is my problem: I have an array of string which contains data like that:

```
array = ["{109}{08} OK",
         "{98} Thx",
         "{108}{0.8}{908} aa",
         "{8}{51} lorem ipsum"]
```

I would like to sort this array scanning "data inside": here the integers in brace. So, the final array should be like that :

```
array.custom_sort! => ["{8}{51} lorem ipsum",
                       "{98} Thx",
                       "{108}{0.8}{908} aa",
                       "{109}{08} OK"]
```

Is there a nice solution to do it in Ruby? Or should I recreate a new array which inserts each parsed elements?

EDIT:

I failed to mention the sort priorities:
First, the sorting is based on the number in braces, up to 3 groups, but cannot be absent.

```
["{5}something",
 "{61}{64}could",
 "{}be",                  #raise an error or ignore it
 "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write",
 "{11}{21}{87}{65}here",  #raise an error or ignore it
 "[]or",                  #raise an error or ignore it
 "{31}not"]
```

If the first numbers are equal, then the second ones should be compared.
Some examples:

```
"{15}" < "{151}" < "{151}{32}" < "{152}"
"{1}" < "{012}" < "{12}{-1}{0}" < "{12.0}{0.2}"
"{5}" < "{5}{0}" < "{5}{0}{1}"
```

But if every numbers are equals, then the string is compares. The only character which make a problem is the space, which must be after every other "visible" characters.
Examples:

```
"{1}a" < "{1}aa" < "{1} a" < "{1}  a"
"{1}" < "{1}a " < "{1}a  " < "{1}a  a"
"{1}a" < "{1}ba" < "{1}b "
```

I can make it doing somethign like this in a custom class:

```
class CustomArray
  attr_accessor :one
  attr_accessor :two
  attr_accessor :three
  attr_accessor :text 

  def <=>(other)
    if self.one.to_f < other.one.to_f
      return -1
    elsif self.one.to_f > other.one.to_f
      return 1
    elsif self.two.nil?
      if other.two.nil?
        min = [self.text, other.text].min
        i = 0
        until i == min
          if self.text[i].chr == ' ' #.chr is for compatibility with Ruby 1.8.x
            if other.text[i].chr != ' '
              return 1
            end
          else
            if other.text[i].chr == ' '
              return -1

          #...

    self.text <=> other.text
  end
end
```

It works fine, but I am very frustrated coding in Ruby like I code in C++ project. That is why I would like to know how to use a "custom sort in a foreach method" with a more complexe sort way (require parsing, scanning, regexp) than a naive one based on an attribute of the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit:** My initial solution, which follows this edit, does not work with the revised statement of the question. I will leave it, however, as it might be of interest regardless.

The following is a way to perform the sort under the revised rules, as I understand them. If I have misinterpreted the rules, I expect the fix would be minor.

**Regex to use**

Let's start with the regex I'll use:

```
R = /
    \{       # match char
    (        # begin capture group
    \d+      # match one or more digits
    (?:      # begin non-capture group
    \.       # match decimal
    \d+      # match one or more digits
    )        # end non-capture group
    |        # or
    \d*      # match zero or more digits
    )        # match end capture group
    \}       # match char
    /x
```

Examples:

```
a = ["{5}something", "{61}{64}could", "{}be", "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write",
     "{11}{21}{87}{65}here", "[]or", "{31}not", "{31} cat"]
a.each_with_object({}) { |s,h| h[s] = s.scan(R).flatten }
  # => {"{5}something"        =>["5"],
  #    "{61}{64}could"        =>["61", "64"],
  #    "{}be"                 =>[""],
  #    "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write"=>["54", "31.24", "0.2"],
  #    "{11}{21}{87}{65}here" =>["11", "21", "87", "65"],
  #    "[]or"                 =>[],
  #    "{31}not"              =>["31"]
  #    "{31} cat"             =>["31"]}
```

**custom_sort method**

We can write the method `custom_sort` as follows (change `sort_by` to `sort_by!` for `custom_sort!`):

```
class Array
  def custom_sort
    sort_by do |s|
      a = s.scan(R).flatten
      raise SyntaxError,
        "'#{s}' contains empty braces" if a.any?(&:empty?)
      raise SyntaxError,
        "'#{s}' contains zero or > 3 pair of braces" if a.size.zero?||a.size > 3
      a.map(&:to_f) << s[a.join.size+2*a.size..-1].tr(' ', 255.chr)
    end
  end
end
```

**Examples**

Let's try it:

```
a.custom_sort
  #=> SyntaxError: '{}be' contains empty braces
```

Remove `"{}be"` from `a`:

```
a = ["{5}something", "{61}{64}could", "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write",
     "{11}{21}{87}{65}here", "[]or", "{31}not", "{31} cat"]
a.custom_sort
  #SyntaxError: '{11}{21}{87}{65}here' contains > 3 pair of braces
```

Remove `"{11}{21}{87}{65}here"`:

```
a = ["{5}something", "{61}{64}could", "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write",
     "[]or", "{31}not", "{31} cat"]
a.custom_sort
  #=> SyntaxError: '[]or' contains zero or > 3 pair of braces
```

Remove `"[]or"`:

```
a = ["{5}something", "{61}{64}could", "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write",
     "{31}not", "{31} cat"]
a.custom_sort
  #=> ["{5}something",
  #    "{31}not",
  #    "{31} cat",
  #    "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write", "{61}{64}could"]
```

**Explanation**

Suppose one of the strings to be sorted was:

```
s = "{54}{31.24}{0.2}write a letter"
```

Then in the `sort_by` block, we would compute:

```
a = s.scan(R).flatten
  #=> ["54", "31.24", "0.2"]
raise SyntaxError, "..." if a.any?(&:empty?)
  #=> raise SyntaxError, "..." if false 
raise SyntaxError, "..." if a.size.zero?||a.size > 3
  #=> SyntaxError, "..." if false || false
b = a.map(&:to_f)
  #=> [54.0, 31.24, 0.2] 
t = a.join
  #=> "5431.240.2" 
n = t.size + 2*a.size
  #=> 16 
u = s[n..-1]
  #=> "wr i te" 
v = u.tr(' ', 255.chr)
  #=> "wr\xFFi\xFFte" 
b << v
  #=> [54.0, 31.24, 0.2, "wr\xFFi\xFFte"]
```

Note that the use of [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) (or you could use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)) puts spaces at the end of the sort order of ASCII characters:

```
255.times.all? { |i| i.chr < 255.chr }
  #=> true
```

**tidE]**

I have assumed that, in sorting, pairs of strings are to be compared in a manner analogous to [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). The first comparison considers the strings of digits within the the first pair of braces in each string (after conversion to a float). Ties are broken by comparing the strings of digits in the second pairs of braces (converted to floats). If there is still a tie, the third pairs digits enclosed in braces are compared, etc. If one string has `n` pairs of braces and another has `m > n` pairs, and the values within the braces are the same for the first `n` pairs, I assume the first string is to precede the second in the sort.

**Code**

```
R = /
    \{    # match char
    (\d+) # capture digits
    \}    # match char
    +     # capture one or more times
    /x

class Array
  def custom_sort!
    sort_by! { |s| s.scan(R).map { |e| e.first.to_f } }
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
array = ["{109}{08} OK",
         "{109}{07} OK",
         "{98} Thx",
         "{108}{0.8}{908} aa",
         "{108}{0.8}{907} aa",
         "{8}{51} lorem ipsum"]

a = array.custom_sort!
  #=> ["{8}{51} lorem ipsum",
  #    "{98} Thx",
  #    "{108}{0.8}{907} aa",
  #    "{108}{0.8}{908} aa",
  #    "{109}{07} OK",
  #    "{109}{08} OK"]

array == a
  #=> true
```

**Explanation**

Let's now calculate the value in [Array#sort_by!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21)'s block for the first element of `array`

```
s = "{109}{08} OK"

a = s.scan(R)
  #=> [["109"], ["08"]] 
b = a.map { |e| e.first.to_f }
  #=> [109.0, 8.0]
```

Let's now do the same for the other strings and put the results in an array:

```
c = array.map { |s| [s, s.scan(R).map { |e| e.first.to_f }] }
  #=> [["{8}{51} lorem ipsum", [8.0, 51.0]],
  #    ["{98} Thx",            [98.0]],
  #    ["{108}{0.8}{907} aa",  [108.0, 907.0]],
  #    ["{108}{0.8}{908} aa",  [108.0, 908.0]],
  #    ["{109}{07} OK",        [109.0, 7.0]],
  #    ["{109}{08} OK",        [109.0, 8.0]]]
```

`sort_by` in `custom_sort!` is therefore equivalent to:

```
c.sort_by(&:last).map(&:first)
  #=> ["{8}{51} lorem ipsum",
  #    "{98} Thx",
  #    "{108}{0.8}{907} aa",
  #    "{108}{0.8}{908} aa",
  #    "{109}{07} OK",
  #    "{109}{08} OK"]
```

Comment: This is very helpful explanation, thanks a lot! But for the string comparison, I forgot to mention something. Let's say: ["{42}foo", "{42}bar","{42}    world","{42} hello"]. The trick is for comparing string, the space character ' ' should be *after* alphanum, but in ASCII table, it does not. I saw in another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808574/ruby-custom-string-sort) that I could set my own "character array" order. Is it possible to integrate this feature in your elegant solution?

Comment: I will have a look at that later today. In the meantime I suggest you edit your question to add the information in your comment (and also to correct the `108` vs `109` ordering if that's required). Because the additional information changes the question, you need to make that clear in the edit.  Often that's done by writing "Edit: I failed to mention...", perhaps at the end of the question.

Comment: You will have to be more precise in explaining the sort criterion. I assumed that the sorted order depended only on the values contained in pairs of braces. Others giving answers made similar assumptions. So, what sorting rules do you want implemented?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
array.sort_by do |s| 
  # regex match the digits within the first pair of curly braces
  s.match(/^\{(\d+)\}/)[1].to_i # convert to an int in order to sort
end

# => ["{8}{51} lorem ipsum", "{98} Thx", "{108}{0.8}{908} aa", "{109}{08} OK"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array.sort_by { |v| (v =~ /(\d+)/) && $1.to_i }
```

alternately

```
array.sort_by { |v| /(\d+)/.match(v)[1].to_i }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can pass [`Array#sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) a block defining how it should order elements.